# How to select value after update at one atomic operation in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Here I want to incr field count, then select count result at one atomic operation.

the code are:

```py
sql = ("update user_cout set count = count+1 "
               "where username=%s")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, (username, ))
cursor.execute("select count from user_count "
                       "where username=%s", (username, ))
```

Any recommendation way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're doing it?

Comment: @Barmar can it work in one statement? those two statement should be a atomic operation

Comment: I think you need to close cursor and reopen it again to get count

Comment: @AshReva I update the question, those two operation should be in an tansaction or in one statement

Comment: Why don't you use START TRANSACTION AND COMMIT to achieve the atomicity?

Comment: To be honest i dont know anything about Python. But from your code it looks like you are updating table and then immediately asking for count in same connection. You need to commit your changes first to database and then reopen the connection.

Comment: @AshReva But if he does that, some other process could update the count and he'll get the wrong value. He wants to stay in the transaction so he gets the value he just assigned.

Comment: @medina Yes, it is one way, I want to know any other way can do it?

Comment: @Barmar oh ok then i got the point but not sure how

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the `UPDATE` and the `SELECT` within a transaction (i.e. statements that are not *automatically* committed):

```
connection.autocommit(0);
```

One can then execute the existing statements and *explicitly* commit them to the database:

```
connection.commit();
```

Note that to achieve atomicity, the `user_count` table must use a transactional storage engine (such as InnoDB).

Answer (score 0):

@linbo, you could create a function/procedure into your database ([check how to do so here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)) and then run just one call in your code:

```
sql = ("SELECT MY_CUSTOM_FUNC(%s)")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, (username, ))
```

There are many advantages of using this approach:

1. You centralize your logic, it can be called from many places in your application;
2. Less code;
3. MySQL uses atomicity by default in functions once it's a simple operation for the db;

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE tbl_name SET pos = @next_pos := pos + 1 WHERE some_id = %s; SELECT @next_pos;", (12345, ))
cursor.nextset()
result = cursor.fetchone()
```

Then `result[0]` will contain incremented value.